# Parse push notification dashboard history

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, dashboard

Is there a way to view push notifications (>30 days ago) from the dashboard/console on parse.com?

I've seen questions on StackOverflow where people were asking for an API to do this. I don't need an API. Just any way to view it from their website.

Thank you